# Error in run command createReportsToolsInstance with WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

I've install the latest version of WebLogic (Middleware) 12.2.1.1.0
and Forms and Reports 12.2.1.1.0

Unfortunately, when you reach for the step create the report tools:

**`createReportsToolsInstance(instanceName='reptools1',machine='AdminServerMachine')`**

I can not continue.
Because I get the following error:

```
Error occurred while performing invoke : Problem finding error class; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilNativeException 
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
createReportsToolsInstance() failed.
```

and This Full DumpStack()

```
This Exception occurred at Thu Aug 25 22:09:56 AST 2016.
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Problem finding error class; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilNativeException
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.getThrowable(ResponseImpl.java:235)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:278)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:292)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_12211_WLStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper$16.run(ClientProviderBase.java:1306)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
    at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:61)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper.invoke(ClientProviderBase.java:1304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.InvocationContextProxyHandler.invoke(ClientProviderBase.java:675)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1020)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.EditHandler.invoke(EditHandler.java:423)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.WLScriptContext.invoke(WLScriptContext.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx124.invoke$48(<iostream>:715)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx124.call_function(<iostream>)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx112.reportsTools_createReportsToolsInstance$7(/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/ReportsToolsComponent/plugins/wlst/reptools-wlst-dependencies.jar!/wlstScriptDir/reports_tools_handler.py:128)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx112.call_function(/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/ReportsToolsComponent/plugins/wlst/reptools-wlst-dependencies.jar!/wlstScriptDir/reports_tools_handler.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx111.createReportsToolsInstance$1(/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/ReportsToolsComponent/plugins/wlst/reptools-wlst-dependencies.jar!/wlstScriptDir/OracleReportsTools.py:22)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx111.call_function(/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/ReportsToolsComponent/plugins/wlst/reptools-wlst-dependencies.jar!/wlstScriptDir/OracleReportsTools.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx131.f$0(<console>:1)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx131.call_function(<console>)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.runsource(WLSTInterpreter.java:1093)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilNativeException
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.WLRMIClassLoaderDelegate.loadClass(WLRMIClassLoaderDelegate.java:212)
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.WLRMIClassLoaderDelegate.loadClass(WLRMIClassLoaderDelegate.java:135)
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.Utilities.loadClass(Utilities.java:305)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.resolveClass(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:455)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream$NestedObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:209)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:625)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.getThrowable(ResponseImpl.java:231)
    ... 57 more
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Problem finding error class; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilNativeException
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the original exception in the WebLogic console too (where you are running the startWebLogic.cmd script).

I had this very same error and in the WebLogic console I discovered that the exception was thrown due missing permissions. The solution is to run the startWebLogic.cmd as Administrator.